# Excel - How to find the average if another row has a value?

Tags: excel

```
ID  Amount
1   100
1   200
1   200
2   400
3   200
```

I want to find the average amount for ID number 1. How to do it?

Comment: Hm, you should probably see the following: [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642)

Comment: I guess [googling the title](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Excel+-+How+to+find+the+average+if+another+row+has+a+value%3F&rlz=1C1CHZL_enCA733CA733&oq=Excel+-+How+to+find+the+average+if+another+row+has+a+value%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of your 'question' never occurred to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula =AVERAGEIF(A1:A5,1,B1:B5)
[image]